# Images in subfolder on unix server not loading on webpage

Tags: image, .htaccess, unix

I have a website hosted on a unix server, with subfolders that have my css file and Images folder in. The

images will not load, not through css and not through directly calling it through the browser.

When calling through the browser all I get is the box you get when the image is non-existant, but when I

call an image in the same folder that doesn't exist it tells me "Not found..".

So it knows there is an image, but it refuses to load it. I've looked around like crazy and finding

suggestions for .htaccess file configuration. All I want to do is load my images

from subfolders. My css file loads and everything else works, just not with loading images.

I repeat, calling http://www.mysite.com/Site/Design/Images/logo.png does not work.

And I will not change my folder hierarchy, the solution must maintain the current structure.

Looking forward to your suggestions,

Thanks

Comment: just check the case of filenames

Comment: I need some `enter` to read it! :)

Comment: @Satya Filenames are exact. I am an experienced web developer and have never had this problem before. But it is my first time working off of a unix server. I usually work off of a linux or windows server. Thank you for the comment though, let me know if you have other suggestions.

Comment: Haha, sorry. Was contemplating spacing it out, but I guess I...spaced out.... :P

Comment: What about a test page with very simple `<img src=...`? Check absolute and relative paths, also navigate through UNIX directories to check if it is exactly the dir you specify.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. I get the same imageless box. It won't even load it if it's in the same directory.

Comment: O.M.G....the files were corrupted during transfer over the Cpanel ftp client....FileZilla for the win...Thank you both for the suggestions. Hope to see you guys again soon.